# horizantal scroll of div is not working

Tags: html, scroll

The vertical scroll works, but the horizontal doesn't.  My code:

```
<html >

<body >
    <table style="  height:100%; width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td >
                <div style=" overflow:scroll; height:100%; width:100%">    
                    <table style="  width:2000px; height:2000px; ">
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>     
                </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to table style with nested tables... it's never going to go well really. I suggest you look for a "CSS Tutorial".

Comment: in which browser?. I think that one is working fine in all browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table is not an ideal element to use unless u want to display a table/table of contents.
Always prefer divs than tables.
This should do inside ur <body>

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 100%; width: 100%">
            <table style="width: 2000px; height: 2000px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

With Table u will have to set  table-layout:fixed ,

```
    <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%; table-layout:fixed">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 100%; width: 100%">
                    <table style="width: 2000px; height: 2000px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%; display:none">
                            </td>

                            <td style="width:50%; display:none">
                            </td>                     
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                              <td>control here will auto-align to 50%</td>
                              <td>control here will auto-align to 50%</td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have modified the td template. Please note that as well.

Comment: my html is very big where lots of tables are used why it is not working inside table

Comment: the table behaves differently in diff browser. So width 100% for a table will take the 100% of container in some browsers, while 100% of the contents in some other browser. If u wanna stick to the table, u have to tell the browser, stay with the container... updated my solution.. hope this helps.. (note: this could affect the td styles, so this expects all tds to be following same width.)

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code like this

```
<html >
<body >
    <table style="  height:100%; width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td >
                <div style=" overflow:scroll; height:2000px; width:100%">    
                    <table style="  width:2000px; height:2000px; overflow:scroll;">
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>     
                </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

try this.it will work..